# Sqllite data fetching took more then a minute for 5000 records

Tags: android, database, sqlite, arraylist

```
//Table Create    
private String CREATE_COST_CENTER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + SQLConstants.TABLE_COST_CENTER + "( "
        + SQLConstants.FIELD_COST_CENTER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + SQLConstants.FIELD_COST_CENTER_NAME + " VARCHAR,"
        + SQLConstants.FIELD_BUSINESS_UNIT_ID + " INTEGER,"
        + SQLConstants.FIELD_COMPANY_ID + " INTEGER)";


 //Insertion of Costcentre
 public synchronized void saveCostCenterItemList(
        List<CostCenterItem> costCenterItemList) {
    if (costCenterItemList == null)
        return;

    database.delete(SQLConstants.TABLE_COST_CENTER, null, null);

    for (CostCenterItem costCenterItem : costCenterItemList) {
        saveCostCenterItem(costCenterItem);
    }
 }

 public long saveCostCenterItem(CostCenterItem costCenterItem) {
    if (costCenterItem == null)
        return -1;

    long rowId = -1;
    database = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    SQLiteStatement insStmt = database.compileStatement("INSERT INTO " + 
    SQLConstants.TABLE_COST_CENTER
            + " (" + SQLConstants.FIELD_COST_CENTER_ID + "," + 
    SQLConstants.FIELD_COST_CENTER_NAME
            + "," + SQLConstants.FIELD_BUSINESS_UNIT_ID + ","+ 
    SQLConstants.FIELD_COMPANY_ID +
            ") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);");
    database.beginTransaction();

    try {
        try {

             insStmt.bindString(1, String.valueOf(costCenterItem.getId()));
            insStmt.bindString(2, costCenterItem.getName());
            insStmt.bindLong(3,  costCenterItem.getBusinessUnitId());
            insStmt.bindString(4, String.valueOf(costCenterItem.getCompanyId()));

            rowId = insStmt.executeInsert();

            database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            database.endTransaction();
        }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        rowId = -1;
    }


  return rowId;

 }

//Fetch Data  
  public ArrayList<CostCenterItem> 
getCostCenterItemListByBusinessIDandCompanyid1(
        int businessUnitId, int companyId ) {
    ArrayList<CostCenterItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = null;

    try {


        cursor = database.query(SQLConstants.TABLE_COST_CENTER, 
null,
                SQLConstants.FIELD_BUSINESS_UNIT_ID + "=" + 
businessUnitId
                        + " AND "
                        + SQLConstants.FIELD_COMPANY_ID + "="
                        + companyId ,
                null, null, null, null);





    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {


        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {

          //  cursor.m

            cursor.moveToPosition(i);

            CostCenterItem item = new CostCenterItem();
            item.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(SQLConstants.FIELD_COST_CENTER_ID)));
            item.setName(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(SQLConstants.FIELD_COST_CENTER_NAME)));
            item.setBusinessUnitId(cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(SQLConstants.FIELD_BUSINESS_UNIT_ID)));
            
 item.setCompanyId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLConstants.FIELD_COMPANY_ID)));

            list.add(item);
        }

    }

} catch (SQLiteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
}

    return list;
}
```

After some research i also index column FIELD_COST_CENTER_NAME in this way
private static final String SQL_CREATE_EMAIL_INDEX =
"CREATE INDEX cost_center_cc_name_idx ON " + SQLConstants.TABLE_COST_CENTER + "
(" + SQLConstants.FIELD_COST_CENTER_NAME + ")";

If i use limit for 500 records then speed is comparitivly fine but that will not solve my purpose as i can't use pagination

[image: My database data]

Comment: Try using moveToNext rather than moveToPosition (you'll need to use moveToFirst for the first one).  That might speed things up, figuring out where it is in the cursor may be an expensive operation

Comment: Hie @GabeSechan  Just tried that but did't worked